# Detecting a context-menu paste in the browser with jquery

Tags: jquery, paste, right-click

I am trying to check the length of the text in a textarea when someone pastes content in there via the right-click but can't seem to find how to do it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$('textarea').bind('paste', function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var length = that.value.length;
        alert(length);    
    }, 0);

});
```

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/4UrE3/1/

Works in Firefox 3.6, Chrome, Safari and IE9 beta.
Does not work in Opera.

Comment: @Sime: Why do you have a `setTimeout` in the function?

Comment: @Rocket Because (in browsers) the pasted text appears in the text-box only after the paste handler has finished. Inside the paste handler, the text-box is still empty. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4UrE3/3/ `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0);` will execute the function immediately after the paste handler has returned and the text-box has been populated, ergo, it is safe to read the `this.value` property.

Comment: @Sime: So, that's why `.bind('paste')` wasn't working before, thanks!

Comment: @Rocket Yes, I guess that's why :)

Comment: This above Fiddler works on Firefox & IE11& CHrome! :)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, but the 'paste' event is not exclusive to context menu. It will also get triggered when the user presses Ctrl+V or Cmd+V. I'm thinking if there's a way to segregate these two actions (keyboard paste and contextmenu paste).

Comment: @mvvijesh - ```$('.foo').on('input paste', function() { ... });```