# Remove extra charecter from textbox on Ctrl V

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeypress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Detecting a context-menu paste in the browser with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702814/detecting-a-context-menu-paste-in-the-browser-with-jquery)

I have a multi-line textbox, which is maximum take 100 character. I have already wrote a JavaScript for restrict up to 100 character, but when I am doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on that textbox it is not removing the extra character. Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: google for how to trim characters in textbox.

Comment: I would suggest prevent user from using paste (ctrl+v) option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeypress`, `onkeyup` as well as `onkeydown` on input text.

Use the below Javascript finction:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtvalueAr" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
onkeypress="return CheckLength(this,160)" onkeyup="return CheckLength(this,160)"
onkeydown="return CheckLength(this,160)" onPaste="return CheckLength(this,160)">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript

```
    function CheckLength(txt, maxLen) {
        try {
            if (txt != null) {
                var iLength = txt.value.length
                if (iLength <= maxLen) //Check the Limit.
                {
                    //Display the remaining characters
                    document.getElementById('character').innerHTML = maxLen - iLength + " are remaining characters.";
                }
                else {
                    txt.value = txt.value.substring(0, maxLen);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the javascript function in `onKeyUp` ,`onblur` and `onmouseout` events.